# Node.js large data sync backend service

Tags: node.js, performance

I am building a data sync backend service that serves a large amount of data to low RAM android clients in under 3 mins.
Currently, we have paginated APIs that we iterate over however, I was hoping to stream data to android clients using Node.js but not sure what the best way forward is.

```
 result.forEach((arrayOfMerchants) => {
   res.write(JSON.stringify({
       status: 200,
       response: arrayOfMerchants,
       message: 'SUCCESS!!',
    }));
  });
  res.end();
```

But it's not cutting it, any help would be appreciated. I would love to stream data in chunks so that we send one request and response in chunks. The code above returns the whole object.

Comment: If you can change your clients to accept [JSONLines](https://jsonlines.org/) / [NDJson](http://ndjson.org/), that would probably work for streaming.

Comment: Have a look at WebSockets.

Comment: We were considering using a message broker and streaming data in chunks that way, however we feared the impact that might have on performance for low RAM devices, eg < 1 GB.
The thought was that we could get 1 request from the user and respond in chunks, so the Transfer-Encoding: chunked but when we tried the above, the client received everything at once.